# jquery function for multiple button event with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").click(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(".no-like").text()) + 1;

    alert(newValue);
    $(".no-like").html(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1" href="#">
 <span class="no-like">35</span> 
</a>

<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1">
  <span class="no-like">3</span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</a>
<a href="">hey</a>
```

Here there are multiple buttons. You need to add 1 value everytime it is clicked. For example: 35 to 36 and 3 to 4 .Jquery must select each button with respective value. But the code is not working even for one button.

Comment: what error is coming, code seems to working fine

Comment: its not working on mine. the value of 35 has to change to 36 when clicked @A.T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use ['this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to refer current instance of element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").click(function() {
    var newValue = +$(this).text() + 1;
    if($(this).find('.no-like').length)
      $(this).find('.no-like:eq(0)').text(newValue);
    else
      $(this).text(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1" href="#">
 35  
</a>

<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1">
  <span class="no-like">3</span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").click(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).text()) + 1;//use this context for clicked element

    alert(newValue);
    $(".no-like").html(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1" href="#">
 35
  
</a>

<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1">
  <span class="no-like">3</span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</a>
<a href="">hey</a>
```

Use this context

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$(this)` for fetched from same element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").click(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).text()) + 1;
    alert(newValue);
    $(".no-like").html(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1" href="#">
 35
  
</a>

<a class="like" data-creation-id="1069347886434951" data-id="1">
  <span class="no-like">3</span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</a>
<a href="">hey</a>
```